# Numpy array множественное присвоение

Tags: python, numpy

имеется код

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([[1, 1], [0, 0]])
c = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
np.savez( file, a=a, b=b, c=c )
res = np.load( "file.npz" )
print( res.files ) # ['a','b','c']
a=res['a'] #[1 2 3]
b=res['b'] #[[1 1],[0 0]]
c=res['c'] #[[1],[2],[3]]
```

Хочется на подобие

```
a,b,c=list(1,2,3)
```

Кто нибут может мне посоветовать как правильно произвести множественое присвоение по именам в массиве, или в цикле с вытягиванием имен из самого массива.
Буду признателен за любую подзказку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант короче:

```
a,b,c = np.load("file.npz").values()
```

результат:

```
In [71]: a
Out[71]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [72]: b
Out[72]:
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 0]])

In [73]: c
Out[73]:
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Comment: Прекрасно а как из списка